# Can you use a Select statement in an joins on clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use a sub query to pick an column to join on to, is this even possible:
if let's say table b has a value that = the column name of table a?
Please note the below example does specify the table_b.Column_A however this is to make my question clearer and less cluttered. The where condition will always return an single value/record.

EDIT: I am trying to basically create an dynamic on clause if that makes any sense.

Further more the only relationship the tables have is that Table_b contains Table_a's columns as values.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b
ON a.(select column1 FROM table_b WHERE Column1 ='Column_A') = b.Column_A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `select` statement in way you are trying but looking to you code you could use and condition  eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.column1 = b.Column_A 
        and b.Column1 ='Column_A'
```

Otherwise if you want build dynamically the query code   you should build server side a string then using this string as  a command

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a INNER JOIN
     table_b b
     ON (b.Column1 = 'Column_A' AND a.column1 = b.column_A) OR
        (b.Column1 = 'Column_B' AND a.column1 = b.column_B) OR
        (b.Column1 = 'Column_C' AND a.column1 = b.column_C)
```

You would have to list out all the columns directly.  Also, `JOIN`s with `OR`s generally have very poor performance.

You can express this more concisely using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b b CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT 'Column_A' as colname, b.Column_A as colval FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Column_B', b.Column_B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Column_C', b.Column_C FROM DUAL 
     ) v JOIN
     table_a a
     ON a.column1 = v.colval
WHERE v.colname = b.Column1
```

Note that this version works in Oracle 12C+.

Comment: I will do a lot of reading on CROSS APPLY as I have never come across it, thank you for exposing me to it.

Comment: @jackd102 . . . It implements a type of join called the "lateral join".  This is a lot like a correlated subquery in the `FROM` clause.  They taking getting used to.  If you remove the `JOIN` to `table_a`, you'll see how it is unpivoting `table_b`.

Comment: @KaushikNayak . . . I really don't recall seeing the Oracle tag when I answered, but tag edits are not recorded with edits.  I adjusted the answer to be more Oracle-friendly.